# An example of a 302 HTTP redirect to a mobile subdomain?

Tags: redirect, mobile, subdomain

Does anyone have an actual example on how to redirect mobile users to a subdomain like m.example.com? I understand that this is preferably done by a 302 HTTP redirect, but I have yet to come across an actual example.

I assume you are looking for client resolution?

**Edit:**

I just found this somewhere. It's meant for wordpress, but I think it could be addapted to work with any website

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# prevent looping
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m.mysite.com$

# if the browser accepts these mime-types, it's definitely mobile, or pretending to be
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC,OR]

# a bunch of user agent tests
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile|windows ce|epoc|opera" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie-"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone|android"[NC]

# rewrite rules here
RewriteRule ^(.+)\$ http://m.mysite.com/$1 [R=302,NC]
```

Comment: What language(s) are you using?

Comment: Language? This is for a htaccess file, but I do not quite understand how you make htaccess recognize the screen resolution.